# Why is my Android app install size different when downloaded from the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I just finished updating an Android app.  I used ProGuard during export and when installed directly from the APK onto my phone the installed size is around 1MB.  After uploading this to the store and installing from the store, the installed size is 2.84MB.  What gives?  Shouldn't these be the exact same since they are the same file?

Some possibilities:

- Google Play does something to the apk file after being uploaded to the store.
- Installing an app from the store goes through an alternate process that causes the size to increase.